# How to display nested routes in different pages using React Hooks..?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

**React Routing V5 --**

Hi, In this Nested react routing, I want to display the 2nd nesting inside Resources page **separately** when i click the corresponding links. Right now it's displaying inside the Products **Id** page. Also, I'm using the { match } for some components, is it fine or it needs to be updated.. maybe by using the useParams, but don't know how to do it as i'm lagging knowledge on it. Also, i want to know how to navigate inside the page.. is it done by using Navlink..? I would be thankful for upgrade to any of the codes below. A CodeSandbox would really help.

Link to -> [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-test-2-rtgy4?file=/src/components/App.jsx:549-596)

My Code as below:

```
       //DATA STRUCTURE
          const Data = [
                {
                 name: "LIGHT FITTINGS",
                 id: "1",
                 
                  resources: [
                               {
                                id: "1a",
                                title: "Bulb",
                                specification: "9W",
                                price: 29.9584,
                                countInStock: 19
                                 },
                                 {
                               id: "2a",
                       title: "Tube light",
                       specification: "9W",
                   price: 39.56,
                   countInStock: 24
                    }
                ]
        },
    {
         name: "SWITCH & SOCKETS",
         id: "2",
             resources: [
                          {
                           id: "1b",
                   title: "Switch",
                   specification: "6A",
                   price: 16,
                   countInStock: 15
                },
              {
            id: "2b",
            title: "Socket",
                specification: "16A",
                price: 39.56,
                countInStock: 24
                }
                  ]
    }
       ];
        export default Data;



   //App.jsx

        import React from "react";
        import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
        import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
        import Products from "../screens/Products";


        function App() {
         return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                

            <div className="mainContent">
                  <Route path={"/product/:productId"} component={ProductId}/>                        
                  <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
                  <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
            </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
            );
            }

        export default App;

   //Product
      import React from "react";
      import Data from "../Data";
      import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

      export default function Products() {
        return (
              <div>
                <h1>First page</h1>
                  <ul>
                    {Data.map(({ name, id }) => (
                     <li key={id}>
                       <Link to={`/product/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
                    </li>
                    ))}
                 </ul>
             </div>
                 );
             }



   //Product ID page
    import React from "react";
    import Data from "../Data";
    import { Link, Route, useRouteMatch, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import Resource from "./Resource";

    export default function ProductId({ match }) {
        let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

     const productItem = Data.find(({ id }) => id === match.params.productId);
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>ProductId page</h2>
                <div>{productItem.name}</div>

                    <ul>
                    {productItem.resources.map((sub) => (
                   <li key={sub.id}>
                        <Link to={`${url}/${sub.id}`}>{sub.title}</Link>
                   </li>
                ))}
                </ul>
    
                <Route path={`${path}/:subId`} component={Resource} />
  
            </div>
         );
         }



    //Resource Page

        import React from "react";
        import Data from "../Data";
        //import { useParams, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

            export default function Resource({ match }) {
             //let match = useRouteMatch();
            //let { subId } = useParams();

        const productItem = Data.find(({ id }) => id === match.params.productId)
                    .resources.find(({ id }) => id === match.params.subId);

        return (
                <div>
                    <h2>Resource Page</h2>
                        <h3>{productItem.title}</h3>
                        <h3>{productItem.price}</h3>
                        <a href={productItem.url}> More Info.</a>
                </div>
            );
            }
```

Comment: You need to put them in different routes. And need to use the `exact` property on the routes so only one shows at a time

Comment: hmm.. i tried to put them in different routes... but i could not do it right. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

1. Add exact in the Route for productId so that all sub routes can be handled separately.

   ```
    <Route exact path={"/product/:productId"} component={ProductId}/>
   ```
2. Create a new Route pointing to subId.

   ```
    <Route path="/product/:productId/:subId" component={Resource} />
   ```

This should solve your issue.

Below is the modified codesandbox with working solution.

[image: Edit Routing Test 2 (forked)]

https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-test-2-forked-k8p64?file=/src/components/App.jsx

Comment: Thank you Sir.. it really did solve my problem. I have one more doubt.. how to navigate inside the page..? say i have a collection of title on the top and when i click it should take to its content which is inside the same page. Is it done using react router.. ?

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Yes using react router you can achieve this and you have already used it in your code.

<HeaderName name={"Light Fittings"} to={"/product/1"} />

This will take you to the Light Fittings Section. 

Also here is one suggestion for you, To list all the products you have used the route as /products and for an individual product, you have used /product/:productId. This should have been /products/:productId Notice the products in /products/: productId. This is not necessary but it is considered a better approach.

Comment if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: You really got my question correct Sir.. I didn't know how to make a separate page so i thougth if i replace the name with /product/ it will show in separate page. I have now added exact path to both /products & /products/:productId and now it is working correctly. Thank you very much Sir. You took the time to answer it.. Thank you..!!